# Is it possible to make a condition in Firestore security rules based on information from the request's ServiceAccountKey.json file?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want my database to be able to be read by anything and to be written only by my python script. In my python script is my ServiceAccountKey.json file. It looks like this (I took all of my information out):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": 
  "private_key_id": 
  "private_key": 
  "client_email":
  "client_id": "
  "auth_uri": 
  "token_uri": 
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
  "client_x509_cert_url":
}
```

Can anything here be a part of a condition in my security rules?

Answer (score 2):

No.  All access to Firestore (and Realtime Database, and Cloud Storage) from a backend/desktop source that's initialized from a service account will always bypass security rules completely.

Security rules only apply to web and mobile clients who are using Firebase Authentication, or no auth at all.

Comment: If I'm not going to have a sign-in system, is no auth the better way to go? There won't be user profiles and whatnot. The app will be the same for everyone using it. I want anything accessing my database to be able to read, but only allow my one python script to write to the database. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Just set your rules to allow everyone to read.  The script will bypass the rules.

Comment: If my script can bypass the rules, can't anyone else in the world do the same?

Comment: No.  As I said in my answer, security rules apply to web and mobile clients. They cannot bypass rules. This is something you can pretty easily try for yourself.

Comment: Ok. I'm using a ServiceAccountKey.json inside both my python script and my iOS app for identifying my database. Is this the correct way to go, or should this only be done for testing purposes?

Comment: You're almost certainly not using that in your iOS app.  Mobile and web clients have a different form of configuration than backend code.

Comment: How would I go about connecting to my database from my IOS app then?

Comment: Hey Doug, so as of right now, my only security rules allow anyone to read and no one to write. I got an email from Google saying "Because your project does not have strong security rules, anyone can access your entire database. Attackers can read all of your data, and they can drive up your bill." With anyone being able to read my database, do I need to check if a user is using my app every time a request to read the database is sent?